# AutoExposure with nonlinear camera: Non linear proportional PID?

Tags: algorithms, control-systems, camera

Now I', wondering how to best implement a control algorithm for it. I tried using a PID controler but started with a simple P-control first. The problem is, that when using the equation `delta_exposure = k*e` whereas `e = mean_grey_is - mean_grey_want = mean_grey_is - 127` and with `k` as a fixed value it is hard to define a good value for `k` because it depends on how big `e` is and on how big the actual `mean_grey_is` is. Assuming `mean_grey_is` is something like 150 (e=23) I'd only need a certain small change of my current ExposureTime. But when `mean_grey_is` something like 173 (`e` is twice as big) and I'm using the same k-value, the change of the ExposureTime obviously would also be twice as big, but to get a fast and quick controlling response, the change of ExposureTime would need to be a lot larger as you could see in the matlab figure above :(

How to do this?

Thanks a lot in advance!

**EDIT2**
@Jazzmaniac: believe me, I don't want you to get frustrated and I really tried and try to describe all the necessary information with completely detailed. Sorry if it wasn't enough so far... The camera has NO auto-exposure or auto-parameter calibration itself, thus does NOT change any parameters itself. I MYSELF did all the measurement above to measure the camera response depending on the different built-in camera parameters. I changed the parameters to a fixed set (v1_0,v2_0,t1_0,t2_0), then varied the ExposureTime while capturing a fixed/constant scene at constant illumination. After that I changed the camera parameters again to a different set (v1_1,v2_1,t1_1,t2_1) and again varied the ExposureTime while capturing the same constant scene at same illumination. That's how I got the different camera responses plotted above (you can clearly see that they heavily depend on the 4 parameters v1,v2,t1,t2 (I plotted for t1=t2=constant)). And still I believe that the camera response varies even for a constant set of parameters (v1,v2,t1,t2)=const with the illumination. And that's exactly the point I was asking about: When I capture the frames with varying ExposureTime in a rather dark room, clearly I need (starting at small exposuretimes) high ExposureTimes to reach the saturation at the mean greylevel 255 in the image. When I keep **everything** constant, turn on the lights in the room and do the SAME measurement again, then I clearly need much smaller ExposureTimes then before to reach the saturation in the image. Therefore, as stated and asked above already, the two camera responses are different concerning the x-axis-scaling. I know you did already state: "Regarding your question with the different x-axis scalings. That doesn't matter,[...]" -> That's what I'm constantly asking about: WHY doesn't it matter? When using the camera response model and calculating the inverse F^(-1)(Vmn) I get complete different values. Was this description detailed enough? I hope so because I tried my hardest to make my question understandable...

**EDIT3**:
@Jazzmaniac: I tried to solve the optimization but I simply couldn't get it working. First of all: I neglected the coefficient $\frac{4}{MN}$ just to simplify it. Shouldn't be a problem I suppose. Therefore I can take the gradient as:

$$ \frac{\partial P[V]}{\partial T} = 2 \sum_{m,n} \left(V_{m,n}-\frac{1}{2} \right)\cdot\left(F'(F^{-1}(V_{m,n}))\cdot F^{-1}(V_{m,n})\frac{1}{T} \right) $$

I'm stuck with different things about it:

1. Is the value of $V_{m,n}$ really only the actual value (because actually the value does iteratively depend on the exposuretime itself via $F(T*A_{m,n})$
2. Is the gradient meant as a function of $T$ as $\frac{\partial P[V]}{\partial T} = g(T)$ or is the $T$ in the gradient the *current* ExposureTime?
3. And how to optimize this now? Sorry I'm not that fit about numerical optimizations. I first thought usually (symbolic maths) you would try to calculate the minimum by solving the equation $\frac{\partial P[V]}{\partial T} = 0 \Leftrightarrow T = ...$ but that's obviously not simply possible is it?

Currently I have the following MATLAB Code:

```
obj = videoinput('gige', 1, 'Mono8');
src = getselectedsource(obj);
src.set('ExposureTime', 5000)

% Functionhandles (camera response f, its inverse f_inv and derivative f_diff)
f = @(x) polyval(fit.coeff, x);
f_inv = @(x) polyval(fit_inv.coeff, x);
f_diff = @(x) (f(x+2)-f(x-2))/4;

% Get image & normalize greyvalues to [0, 1]
IMG = getsnapshotfcn(obj);
IMGnorm = double(IMG(:))/255;

% The total penalty:
P = sum((IMGnorm-0.5).^2);

% The gradient of P in dependance of T as a function handle dPdT = g(T)
dPdT = @(T) 2*sum((IMGnorm-0.5).*f_diff(f_inv(IMGnorm)).*1/T.*f_inv(IMGnorm));
```

Comment: Regarding your edit: It's not quite clear to me why the curves would saturate at gray levels that are not at or near 255. How exactly do you produce these curves?

Comment: That's the key of the compression of the linlog camera: The ability to apply a high compression to high intensity pixels (like a logarithmic curve). How I produce them? I let the camera point into a constant scene (one-coloured, plain motive which is evenly illuminated to produce ideally only ONE intensity) while keeping the illumation constant. Then I'm varying the linlog values (those are T1, T2, V1, V2) and then for a fixed set of linlog-values I vary the ExposureTime, thus getting only a very very small histogram and therefore calculating the mean-value...

Comment: But I don't know if that's the point of interest at all? Because the measured curve certainly depends on the overall Illumination and if you capture one indoor and one outdoor, they certainly differ in how big the ExposureTime needs to be to reach a certain greylevel in the histogram. Therefor, the question arises how to program the controller when using the same qualitative camera response curve with different values on the x-axes... :)

Comment: Ok, it still doesn't make a lot of sense to me. Even for a lin-log camera (which I've used before) the response usually uses the full dynamic range of the output representation, i.e. the full 8 bit integer range from 0 to 255. So the yellow curve doesn't make any sense to me. Saturating at around 75 seems like a very useless setting and wastes 70% of the dynamic range. Regarding your question with the different x-axis scalings. That doesn't matter, the intensity domain of the model is agnostic of scaling, as long as the transfer function and the inverse match up.

Comment: Yeah the yellow curve isn't meant to be used like that but why shouldn't it make sense in a theoretical measure on a fixed scene? I mean the linlogparameters probably just were set TOO high thus I wouldn't use them in a productive system, but as result of a theoretical measure, I don't see what should be wrong with them. And still I don't understand why the different x-scalings don't harm the algorithm as the inverse of a pixel value F^(-1)(Vmn) would give me two complete different values for two different x-axis scalings.

Comment: Yes, the values change, but they're meaningless without context. Only the mappings are important. The model itself is invariant under a scaling of your x-axis.

Comment: It's me again. Looking at the photonfocus manual, I see some example curves: http://s21.postimg.org/kljnfat7b/screenshot_34.png So there you see: Such curves exist. No doubt those settings don't make sense being used in a productive scenario, but they just come up like that when being measured with all combinations of different settings (including those which are useless)

Comment: You'll just have to calibrate for one set of parameters (and also make sure that you fit a relatively smooth curve to your measurements, because some of the small features are surely artifacts). If you change the camera lin-log mapping you will have to recalibrate. But that's true for any model, unless you find a parametrization for your curve (maybe based on the camera specifications) that allows you to calculate the response curve just from the camera parameters

Comment: @Jazzmaniac Sorry I may be annoying, but I simply don't quite understand it as you do neither give me a detailed description nor the reasons for it which makes it hard for me to get the point. Let's assume I've measured the camera response and found a regression for it. Now how am I supposed to use your described penalty model when the camera response was only valid for the measured lightning conditions and NOT in general because it may vary heavily in a different situation. How am I supposed to use the same camera response curve by doing a simple recalibration?

Comment: And further: What will happen if I'm driving around with the camera installed and the weather changes from bright sunny to a foggy, rainy or cloudy weather? I still want to be able to use the AE algorithm without recalibration... Sorry but I really want to understand it but I simply can't because I am lacking necessary information and reasons in form of facts

Comment: well I have the same frustration because I get the feeling you're not really telling me all the details. So does the camera automatically change its parameters if the lighting conditions change? If not then your response doesn't change, you only move to a different part of the same response. I still think you should try to understand the internal intensity mapping of the camera and create a mathematical description for it with all the parameters. Then you don't have to calibrate at all.

Comment: As it's gotten a quite long comment (trying to be detailed as much as I possibly could), I edited it above into **EDIT2**. I hope it's clear now what I'm concerned about?!

Comment: Ok, so that clears things up and confirms the situation I was assuming. The variation in exposure time scaling is to be expected, because you're not really measuring against exposure time but intensity. But the model I gave you does not need an absolute measure of intensity, any scale proportional to intensity gives exactly the same result, because the scaling factors from the transfer function and its inverse cancel with the derivatives. Also note that nowhere in the final equation are there any references to the intensities, all is just pixel values, which is all you measure.

Comment: So you can either trust me on that assertion or you do the math yourself by introducing an arbitrary scaling factor to the intensities $A_{m,n}$ and propagate that change through the inverse and the derivatives and see them cancel in the end result. That scaling really only sets the unit of the intensity measurement, and we never made any use of that. So you don't have any problem.

Comment: Okay thanks once again, I'm glad I could clear things up now :-) i'll try it!

Comment: I tried a quick measurement to confirm that two curves under different illumination are ONLY different by a constant scaling factor: I set the camera to a constant (one constant plane) motive again, set the lightning in the room to 90%, measured it. Then did it again with 100% lightning. Then I searched two measured values with the same mean-greyvalue and calculated the quotient of the exposuretimes. When now scaling the exposuretimes of one dataset it results in exactly the second dataset. So that's true :-) Here the visual results: http://s22.postimg.org/jajxlsvpt/screenshot_37.png

Comment: So the camera response stays really the same qualitatively :-) Just wanted to post it to show you the quick confirmation. I know there's one outliner but that doesn't harm in this case! :-)

Comment: have you seen that I have added some additional details to the answer? I thought you might find it helpful to understand how the answer relates to your previous approach.

Comment: No, I actually didn't. Thanks for pointing it out! I'll look into it now, thank you so much so far :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you know the exact response of the camera, you can convert the brightness samples of each pixel to a linear intensity scale and perform the averaging there. That will make your whole problem intensity linear and should solve all your problems.

However, I would strongly recommend using a more advanced exposure algorithm. For example you could introduce a penalty function that gets large for very low intensities and very high intensities. Summing up the penalty of all pixels gives you a total penalty that you can minimize by changing the exposure time. If the penalty is nicely behaved (smooth, etc) then you can use fast converging optimization algorithms.

As requested I will briefly describe a possible implementation of the penalty method.

Your variables are the *exposure time* $T$, the *pixel values* $V_{m,n}\in [0,1]$ for $m\in 1.. M$ and $n \in 1..N$. You also have the invertible transfer function $F$ of the camera that maps real physical intensities to pixel values. This function is also differentiable and its derivative is $F'$.

With this we can express the pixel values in terms of the physical intensities $A_{m,n}$ and the exposure time $T$ as:
$$V_{m,n} = F\left(T A_{m,n} \right)$$

Next we introduce a penalty functional that assigns high scores to very dark and very bright regions and low scores to well lit regions. Note that you can have more than just one free parameter (here exposure time) and a more complicated penalty model. I'll just go for the simplest sensible one. The penalty functional is

$$ P[V] = \frac{4}{MN}\sum_{m,n} \left(V_{m,n}-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2$$

Now we can plug in our exposure model

$$ P[V] = \frac{4}{MN}\sum_{m,n} \left(F(TA_{m,n})-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2$$

and see how the penalty changes with the exposure time

$$ \frac{\partial P[V]}{\partial T} = \frac{4}{MN} \sum_{m,n} 2\left(F(TA_{m,n})-\frac{1}{2} \right)\cdot\left(F'(TA_{m,n})\cdot A_{m,n} \right) $$

This expression unfortunately depends on the unknown physical intensities $A$. But we can use the exposure model again, but inverted, to estimate those from the pixel values we have. That means with $T A_{m,n} = F^{-1}(V_{m,n})$ and therefore also $A_{m,n}=F^{-1}(V_{m,n})/T$ we get

$$ \frac{\partial P[V]}{\partial T} = \frac{8}{MN} \sum_{m,n} \left(V_{m,n}-\frac{1}{2} \right)\cdot\left(F'(F^{-1}(V_{m,n}))\cdot F^{-1}(V_{m,n})\frac{1}{T} \right) $$

Summing up, you can use the pixel values $V_{m,n}$ from just one measurement to calculate both the penalty and its gradient, using even just an approximate model of your camera. With value and slope you can then start to iteratively search for the minimum penalty by descending the gradient in some clever way.

How exactly you do that is a matter of experimentation and taste. But with the square based model here I would suggest you use a *parabolic approximation* of the penalty function to guess the minimum.

Also note that I chose the penalty so that it is normalized between 0 and 1. So you can use that scale to decide if a found minimum is well exposed absolutely or not. This could be useful as a quality indicator for your images.

**Addendum**: For sake of completeness let me quickly show how this model generalizes your approach as described in the question.

Assume that the camera is in fact linear, and that the response function is therefore
$$F(A)=s A$$ for some proportionality factor $s$. The derivative is then $F'(A)=s$ and the inverse $F^{-1}(V)=\frac{V}{s}$. With this special case, the gradient of the penalty becomes $$\frac{\partial P[V]}{\partial T}=\frac{8}{MN} \sum_{m,n}\left(V_{m,n}-\frac{1}{2} \right)\cdot \left( \frac{V_{m,n}}{T}\right)$$
and the intensity scaling factor $s$ cancels. Finding an extremum of this penalty function corresponds to choosing $T$ so that the gradient vanishes.
$$\sum_{m,n}\left(V_{m,n}-\frac{1}{2} \right)\cdot V_{m,n}=0$$

Now let us quickly consider the trivial case where all $V_{m,n}=V$ are constant and not equal to zero. Then we can divide by $V$ and get that $V-1/2=0$ or $V=1/2$. With our convention of $V$ being in $[0,1]$ that means the solution is a constant flat image of 50% gray.

Of course all $V_{m,n}$ being identical is a very non practical assumption. So let's look at the more general case and expand the product in the sum.
$$\sum_{m,n}V_{m,n}^2-\frac{1}{2} V_{m,n}=0$$
or written slightly different
$$\sum_{m,n} \left( V_{m,n}-\frac{1}{2} \right)^2 + V_{m,n} - \frac{1}{4} - \frac{1}{2} V_{m,n}=0$$
and after collecting and scaling
$$\sum_{m,n} 2\left( V_{m,n}-\frac{1}{2} \right)^2 + V_{m,n} = \frac{1}{2}$$
We can express that with the mean brightness $\langle V \rangle$ and the quadratic deviation from the 50% brightness $\Delta V$ as 
$$ 2 \Delta V + \langle V \rangle = \frac{1}{2}$$

For very small deviations $\Delta V$ we get the solution you proposed in your question, namely $\langle V \rangle = \frac{1}{2}$. But the more brightness variations you have in the picture the bigger the (strictly positive) deviation becomes, and the mean brightness must drop below $\frac{1}{2}$.

So this model generalizes your proposal for greater brightness variations, and that is very important. Because a picture that is black almost everywhere but has some small area with very high intensity would still be over exposed if you just make the mean brightness equal to 1/2. The huge variation will however make sure that the mean brightness will be chosen to be significantly lower, and save your result from over exposure!

Comment: first of all, thank you very much. unfortunately I dont know the exact response since it depends on several variables which can be configured and there's no formular for the response-curve. But I know it at least "roughly" if that could help!? But the approach with the penalties sounds interesting. But how could I know then when to increase or decrease the Exposuretime when I only have a value of penalties which I want to minimize?

Comment: Id like to implement an autoexposure algorithm which adopts to some sort of mathematical algorithm or to some math-formulas and not something like "trial-and-error". I hope you know what I mean - because it's used in a scientific area and therefore has to be justified, e.g. by maths :)

Comment: @bjoern, I'm a mathematical physicist, so I'm exactly on your page. Optimizing the penalty means you look for a global minimum of the penalty function (if the penalty is well designed then there's only one local minimum, or several very close ones that all work well). How exactly you look for that minimum depends on the optimization algorithm you employ. A smooth penalty function would suggest a gradient based algorithm. If your math skills are sufficient, you can derive the gradient analytically, if not you can just evaluate the penalty function at two nearby points and find the slope.

Comment: From there you can estimate a new exposure parameter that lies in descending direction, and depends on the value of the gradient. There are many optimization strategies, most with known convergence requirements and speeds.

Comment: It sounds interesting but I still do not understand how to design or how to calculate the penalty function. I mean okay, I can calculate the current penalty value, which is a fixed value for the current snapshot/capture of my camera -> but how should I get the penalty values for snapshots with different exposuretime which I haven't event captured? As far as I understand I have to calculate all penalty values so that I can then derive the minimum of it?

Comment: @bjoern, No, you just know the theoretical connection between the penalty as a function of pixel values and the actual penalty value at your image sample. The rest is blind optimization. That means you move to where you expect the penalty to be lower and take another picture. Then iterate from the start.

Comment: But blind optimization sounds not good in this case. I mean, with the PID controller already I know in which direction to optimize: If the above mentioned `e` is `e>0` then I know at least I've got to decrease the exposuretime and the other way round. The only problem still is that I don't know how much to decrease...

Comment: @bjoern, you also know the direction if you find the gradient of the penalty function. You can either evaluate the gradient analytically using just one measurement (and known properties of the penalty function) or two nearby measurements and taking their numerical difference. There is absolutely no disadvantage compared to your method.

Comment: Could you please provide a detailed information about how to calculate and design the penalty function for my image brightness out of my current camera-snapshot because I still don't understand exactly how to make use of it. Thank you very much!

Comment: Cool thank you very much, that sounds very interesting. The only problem I currently see is: I don't know the transfer function F since der camera vendor doesn't have it as a formular. I only know a qualitative trend/characteristic. And furthermore I can't even measure it, because I don't know which intensity comes in and which pixel values those map to in the camera. But what I think of: Maybe it would be enough to have a "rought" estimation of the camera characteristic? Problem is then again: It depends on the 4 linlog parameters and can be quite differently

Comment: See here: http://imgur.com/a/nGyRd/all any idea on how to solve this? But if I knew the characteristics, your approach would be very nice, thanks though so far :-)

Comment: @bjoern, the camera response function is not all that important. The gradient will still point in the right direction if you get it wrong. However, you should be able to measure it by just increasing the exposure time for a constant motive, because the exposure time enters the total intensity linearly. So the graph you posted above IS already your transfer function!

Comment: Is it really? I thought it's not quite the transfer function because it is the function which shows the dependance of the MEAN greyvalue of a scene of the exposuretime and not depending on the intensity. So it's quite similar, but not exactly the camera-response-function!? But I assume I need the transfer function as a math formular, right? So I'd need to do some sort of regreesion to get `F` as invertible equation, right? EDIT: Whats the exact name of such an approach so that I could do a bit more research about it? :-) Thank you very very much SO far, really helped // I hope more to come :-)

Comment: Yes, you're right, it's not exactly the transfer function. But you can make it more exact if you just take a picture of one single object with homogeneous brightness and measure the average pixel value over it, depending on the exposure time. Or you take just any picture and average just over an area of roughly equal brightness. And once you have it you can simply use an interpolation function or if you want a regression model. Spline interpolation should work well though. And I'm not aware of a general name for this kind of approach other than nonlinear optimization.

Comment: I edited my post because I'm facing a huge problem with your approach... Do you know an answer or do you have an idea how to solve or treat the situation? maybe you could update your answer! thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Hey there, it's me again, I tried to solve the problem myself but was stuck with the numerical optimization. Do you maybe could help me out with it? Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: @bjoern, sure, maybe in a chat? Let me know what you have problems with and I can try to help you.

Comment: Yes please, I'll try to stop by later today.

Comment: Hey jazzmaniac, leider verlässt man immer automatisch den Chat // kannst du alles lesen, was ich dazwischen geschrieben habe, auch wenn du ihn zwischendrin verlässt? weil alles hier zu posten wird wohl schnell unübersichtlich und länglich... ;)

Comment: Long overdue... ;-)

Comment: hey bjoern! Hope your thesis is going well. The reason for this model is physics really. An imaging sensor (or even an analog film) works by "counting photons" or rather, integrating the total effect on it during the exposure time. This means it doesn't matter if you have low intensity for a long time or high intensity for a short time, as long as the same number of photons arrives at the sensor. So you always have a product between intensity and time that is relevant for the sensor, because that's all the physics cares about.